# Bidirecional binding in Javafx StringProperty is not working in inverse direction

Tags: binding, javafx

I have a classical JavaBean which will be bond with a JavaFX TextField.

```
public class Cell {

    public static final String CELL_VALUE = "Cell.Value";

    private Optional<Integer> value;

    private final PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);


    public Optional<Integer> getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Optional<Integer> value) {
        Optional<Integer> old = this.value;
        this.value = value;
        this.pcs.firePropertyChange(CELL_VALUE, old, value);
    }

    /**
     * The values must be from 1 to 9. 0 or null will be converted to Option.none.
     */
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.setValue(Optional.of(value));
    }

}
```

Also I created a StringConverter subclass:

```
import java.util.Optional;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class CellValueStringConverter extends StringConverter<Optional<Integer>> {

    @Override
    public String toString(Optional<Integer> value) {
        System.out.printf("toString()   : %s%n", value);
        return value.isPresent()? String.valueOf(value.get()): "";
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Integer> fromString(String string) {
        System.out.printf("fromString() : %s%n", string);
        if(string.matches("^[1-9]$")) {
            return Optional.of(Integer.valueOf(string));
        }
        if(string.isEmpty() || string.matches("^( |0)$")) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal value for a Cell: " + string);
    }


}
```

In the controller class, before the main stage become visible, I made the binding between Cell value and TextField:

```
ObjectProperty<Optional<Integer>> valueProperty = JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder.create().bean(cell)
        .name("value").build();
final StringProperty textProperty = textField.textProperty();
// Binding ...
textProperty.bindBidirectional(valueProperty, new CellValueStringConverter());

textField.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, me -> {
    if (me.getClickCount() == 2) {
        cell.setValue(random.nextInt(8) + 1);
    }
});

        textProperty.addListener(
                (ov, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.printf("textProperty : %s -> %s%n", oldValue, newValue));
        valueProperty.addListener(
                (ov, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.printf("valueProperty: %s -> %s%n", oldValue, newValue));
        cell.addPropertyChangeListener(
                evt -> System.out.printf("cell         : %s -> %s%n", evt.getOldValue(), evt.getNewValue()));
```

When I start the application, I get the message `toString()   : Optional.empty`. When I type a value (Let's say "4") in an empty TextField, these messages are printed:

```
fromString() : 4
cell         : Optional.empty -> Optional[4]
valueProperty: Optional.empty -> Optional[4]
textProperty :  -> 4
```

If I type "8" in this TextField I got this:

```
fromString() : 
cell         : Optional[4] -> Optional.empty
valueProperty: Optional[4] -> Optional.empty
textProperty : 4 -> 
fromString() : 8
cell         : Optional.empty -> Optional[8]
valueProperty: Optional.empty -> Optional[8]
textProperty :  -> 8
```

Finally, if I type "0", the Cell Will become empty:

```
fromString() : 
cell         : Optional[8] -> Optional.empty
valueProperty: Optional[8] -> Optional.empty
textProperty : 8 ->
```

So far, so good. But I if double click over the TextField, instead replace the text, nothing happens. Suppose that the cell value (and the texfField) is 4. When I double click, I get this message:

```
cell         : Optional[4] -> Optional[8]
```

However the textField continues showing "4". The message in `CellValueStringConverter.toString()` is not showed.

Supposedly, when I wrapped the cell value in a `ObjectProperty` (`JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder.create().bean(cell).name("value").build()`), it should observe all changes in the value property. But is is not occuring. What is missing here?

Thanks,

Rafael Afonso

Answer (score 0):

I think that I found a answer or at least a workaround. I had to add a new `PropertyChangeEvent` to my `Cell` object to that when the `Cell.value` attibute is changed, the valueProperty is directly setted:

```
cell.addPropertyChangeListener(evt -> {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final Optional<Integer> newValue = (Optional<Integer>) evt.getNewValue();
    valueProperty.set(newValue);
});
```

At least, the things started to work as expected. When I double ciclk over an empty TextField, I get these messages:

```
cell         : Optional.empty -> Optional[2]
toString()   : Optional[2]
textProperty :  -> 2
valueProperty: Optional.empty -> Optional[2]
```

And the textField is filled as expected. However, I thought strange that valueProperty message is the last to be printed althought his setter had been the first thing to be called.

If someone have a better idea, it will be welcome.